# Separate Checkout Flow in Magento bypassing Cart/Quote

Tags: checkout, cart, quote, store-credit

I have been researching this for a while, did not find anything related to this anywhere.

**Situation:**

> Our client sells Groceries on his Magento store. We have implemented
>   Store Credit feature using Magestore's Store Credit extension. We call
>   this feature as Wallet.
>  Customers would be able to add
>   credits to the Wallet by purchasing them. This feature is inbuilt in
>   the extension.
>  In the extension, purchasing Wallet credits is
>   like purchasing any other product. You have to go to the product page,
>   add desired credits amount, add the "Store Credits" product to the
>   cart and checkout.

**Problem:**

> We want to have a different checkout flow for purchasing store
>   credits. **We want to bypass the entire concept of cart/quote.**
>  When customer
>   enters desired "Store Credit" amount and clicks "Buy", he should be
>   taken directly to the checkout page or the payment page (whichever is
>   easier). The concept of cart or quote should not be used.
>
> For
>   example, let's say a customer adds some normal products to the cart.
>   Then he tries to add some credits to his Wallet (Store Credit). When
>   he clicks pay, he should be taken to the checkout/payment page, where
>   he pays only for Store Credits amount. After payment he would be redirected back to Store Credits page.
> The products he added to the
>   cart remains intact.

Is this possible in Magento? If yes, how complex would it be? Has anyone done this? Is there any extension?